# Не появляется скроллбар в дочернем контейнере

Tags: css, less

Возникла проблема со скроллингом в приложении на Electron'е. Есть страница, в которую построчно выводится данные. Для вывода большого количества строк реализован скроллинг:

```
.main-panel-content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: ~"calc(100vh - @{headerHeight} - @{toolbarHeight})";
    margin-left: 6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Все это отлично работает, но возникла необходимость в определенном случае выводить данные на эту страницу не в тот блок, для которого применяется вышеуказанный стиль, а во вложенный в него блок меньшего размера. Соответственно, нужно в этом случае как-то отменить скроллинг в родительском блоке и назначить в дочерний. Есть ли способы реализовать что-то подобное? Вешаю на дочерний контейнер стиль, аналогичный вышеуказанному - скроллбар все равно появляется в родительском контейнере. Совсем отрубаю скроллбар родительского контейнера (хотя этого делать нельзя) - не появляется вообще никакого.

HTML-структура в общих чертах такова:

```
<div className="main-panel-content»> // на этом блоке скроллинг есть сейчас
    <div className="page-header main" />
    <div className="input-wrapper">
                <input 
                    onChange={this.onChange} 
                    onFocus={this.onFocus} 
                    onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
                    value={this.state.query} 
                    tabIndex={0} 
                />
    </div>
    <div className="search-rslt"> // на этот блок хочу повесить скроллинг
    …
    </div>
</div>
```

Буду благодарен за любые ответы.

Comment: Напишите структуру html чтоб было понятно.

Comment: Упс, прошу прощения. Добавил.

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант, вы можете сделать такую логику, что:

Если выводится этот блок `search-rslt`, то его родителю `main-panel-content` добавить какой-то класс, допустим `no-scroll`.

И теперь что мы имеем? Пишем новый `css`:

```
.main-panel-content.no-scroll {
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```